# Regex for fixed length string, starting with number 0

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap validator and try to validate a fixed length string with regex.

The string has a fixed length of exactly 7 alphanumeric characters and uses the format `AAA B-C`, for which...

- `AAA` is three digit number range between `001-185` with leading `0`
- followed by a `space`
- `B` is character only accepting `A-F`
- followed by a `-`
- `C` is one digit number only accepting `1-4`

For example, the followings are correct matches:

```
001 A-1
056 F-3
138 B-1
```

Please I need help finding the right regex, thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple regex is ^[0-1][0-9][0-9] [A-F]-[1-4]$ but it will match 199 at the start as well so its not completely accurate. You would be better to write a custom validation in javascript and convert the first part to a number and check it is not greater than 185

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the alternation operator (|). It is basically the OR operator in regex.
It's a bit unwieldy, but here's the regex for your case:

```
^(0[0-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9]|18[0-5]) [A-F]-[1-4]$
```

Explanation:

`^`: Start of Regex

`(`: Capturing group start

`0[0-9][0-9]`: Literal match for zero followed by any two numbers

`|`: Alternative (match either the left regex or the right regex)

`1[0-7][0-9]`: Literal match for 1 followed by 0-7 in the tens place followed by any number. 
We need to split up 100-179 and 180-185 since the units place for 180 and above can't be >5.

`|`: Alternative (match either the left regex or the right regex)

`18[0-5]`: Literal match for 18 followed by any number in the units place.

`)`: Capturing group end

`[A-F]-[1-4]`: space followed by any character in A to F followed by - followed by any number in 1 to 4. (Note that there is a space at the front)

`$`: Ensure match is at end of the string.

You can check your regex in some site online, for example, https://regex101.com/.

Another option is to do regex twice. Taking a simpler regex from user Rosco to filter some input:

```
if(^[0-1][0-9][0-9] [A-F]-[1-4]$ matches in input){
     // check if anything is above 185
     // we already know that input is off form [0-1][0-9][0-9] [A-F]-[1-4]
     // thus we only need to check the second and third character when the first is 1
     if(^18[6-9]....$ matches in input or ^19[0-9]....$ matches in input)
           //input doesn't match your required regex
}
```